# Is saving data in SQLite as BLOB, a good programming practice?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, sqlite

Currently I am working with the project in which I need to parse complex XML, which contains multilevel details (Name & Paths for PDFs, PNGs, etc) at each node.

I need to store all the data in local memory of iPhone/iPad.

Should I create classes for each of those details and make appropriate tables in SQLite **or** store the data as BLOB and retrieve all the data all the time?

Any Suggestions, thoughts are most welcome...

**EDIT:**

I am storing Files in DocumentsDirectory and path to SQLite database. Question is to create well defined database tables or to store data in BLOB form.

Pros and Cons for both approach would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my opinion you should simply use BLOB : when you startup your app load you'r xml into an object all changes will be made to that object so you can win the time to rewrite back to disk
on exit application save all to disk..

Answer (score 1):

Using of BLOB is not a good process .Store all pdf and images in Document directory..store that path only in DB...

Comment: I am storing it as you suggested from start. That's not my question. My question is: "Whether to define proper database schema or use data  as it comes(blob)." Hope u get my question, now.